# How to extract human-readable data using Wiki-data toolkit api?

Tags: java, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, wikidata

I am using wikidata to fetch data for research.

My goal is for each given name, e.g. Abdias Praetorius, get the entity's id, dob, place of birth, sex etc .

The page is :
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q308161
And it seems easy.

But when I used wiki-data *FetchOnlineDataExample.java* code and modified it a little bit. Then I get some information like this:

```
{de=["Abdias Praetorius" (de), "Gottschalk Schultze" (de)]}
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P21 :: http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6581097 (item)
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P19 :: http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q486985 (item)
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P20 :: http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6837 (item)
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P27 :: http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q183 (item)
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P214 :: "20740552"
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P227 :: "128621761"
...
```

This is sweet. Because it's literally defined in the web page, e.g.
"place of death" is an item in page:

```
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P20
```

"Wittenberg" is an item in page:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6837
```

My question is:
Is there any way I can scrap only "place of birth:wittenberg"? I know it might be doable to just crawled the whole web page and read the dom data. I am just curious if there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wbgetentities API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities) to fetch the label of an item or property. There is also [a third-party API](http://api.haykranen.nl/) which uses Wikidata in the background but has a more convenient result format: http://api.haykranen.nl/wikidata/entity?q=308161